# What's a calendar + to do list app that will work on both my MacBook Air and iPhone

Tags: macos, ios, software-recommendation, calendar

I've looked all over for such an app, however the ones I find are either calendar apps (e.g. Sunrise Calendar) or to do list apps (e.g. Any.do).

I was wondering if anyone knew of an app that had both these functionalities and was available both on my MacBook Air running 10.12 as well as on my iPhone running iOS 10.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in Calendar, Notes, Alarm & Reminders functionality - or what else do you need that these don't provide? Personally, for additional functionality I use AnyList, but that requires subscription to enable web-based functions.

Comment: Fantastical is $50

Answer (score 1):

Busycal is a wonderful calendar app that is a more fully featured version of iCal (predecessor to the even-less-imaginatively-named Calendar).   BusyCal does include ToDo List capability with multiple lists, which can be associated with specific calendars.  Can include tags, alarms, priority, notes, etc.

One of my favourite things about BusyCal is that it is not a slave to month boundaries, so the "month" view can include 2-12 weeks and can start whenever you want.  I find it much more useful to see the next six weeks from today, than to see the rest of this arbitrary calendar month!  Also the text color (rather than the silly dot) indicates which calendar an entry is associated with.  Weather forecasts for the next ten days are also added (optionally), which is great for planning outings! This screenshot shows those big -- they can also be just tiny.

http://www.busymac.com/busycal/

[image: busycal screenshot]
<sub>(source: [dreamcss.com](http://static.dreamcss.com/wp-content/uploads/busycal.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Apple calendar and reminder are the canonical calendar and task tools and integrate and sync well via iCloud for many that don’t need enterprise lists or single pane UI.

Th non canonical popular single pane choice has to be Microsoft Outlook. It of course also tightly integrates email function and the 2016 version does require a subscription of some sort. Both are first class native apps for iOS and macOS and deserv a fresh look if you had opinions and experi nice using them in the past on OS X and weren’t impressed or worse.

Other very solid programs that mix in function between single pane and two tools are:

- Fantastical
- BusyCal
- Calendar 5 by readdle
- Timepage
- OmniFocus
- Things

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Sunrise so I'm not sure what your objection is. I assume it's just that it doesn't support to-dos? Fantastical is a calendar app that supports both events/appointments and todos.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.hashtagtodo.com

Integrates to-do functionality within Google Calendar events. Works anywhere you already view your calendar (browser or any client).